# What are $s$-wave collisions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In several articles on quantum physics, I found written "$s$-wave collisions". However, even after looking it up on the Internet, I can't quite figure out what this refers to: most of the results already assume that the reader knows what this is.

For example [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.05913), in order to cool down atoms, these atoms are transferred to a state causing $s$-wave interactions, which apparently help evaporative cooling. Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atom cooling involves photons interacting with atoms. These interactions are sometimes called scattering. The system undergoing the scattering has an angular momentum squared observable $\hat{L}^2$, which has eigenvalues $\hbar^2 l(l+1)$. The wave function of that system can be decomposed in terms of waves with different values of $l$: each term is called a partial wave. The term s-wave scattering refers to the partial wave for $l=0$ and s-wave scattering is studied because this term is usually larger than the others, see

[http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/handout_scattering.pdf](http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Ebds10/aqp/handout_scattering.pdf)